# MySQL Add row to table where one value exists but not another

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if 'm asking this right, but how do I add a new row where customer group = 0 for every file_id where customer_group_id = 0 does not exist yet.  Basically EVERY file_id should have every customer_group_id, but some are missing group 0 and 1.

```
|-----------------------------------------|
|id    |file_id|store_id|customer_group_id|
|-----------------------------------------|
|16389 |8376   |0       |1                |
|44241 |8376   |0       |2                |
|19669 |8376   |0       |3                |
|23765 |8376   |0       |11               |
|27861 |8376   |0       |21               |
|31956 |8376   |0       |31               |
|36051 |8376   |0       |61               |
|40146 |8376   |0       |71               |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: a new row - "XXXX" "8376"      "0"         "0"
Basically, if a file_id EXISTS and DOES NOT have a customer_group_id of 0, add it

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `INSERT` with the rows you are missing. Something like:

```
insert into my_table (file_id, store_id, customer_group_id)
select file_id, '0', '0'
from my_table
where file_id not in (
  select file_id
  from my_table
  where customer_group_id = 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if these fields are unique indexes, you can put insert ignore or replace into ....